# Passing multiple methods in props ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main `App` component that includes this...

```
changeAmount(a) {
  console.log('changing: ', a);
}

<Table 
     data={result}
     onClick={() => this.changeAmount()}
/>
```

The `<Table>` component then has a `<TableRow>` component which has two buttons within it. Is there a way to pass multiple `onClick` methods so I can use one for `decrease` and one for `increase` ?

```
export default class TableRow extends Component {
  render() {
    const {row, onClick} = this.props;
      return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            .....
            <span>

              <button 
                 className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm minusBtn"
                 onClick={onClick}
              >
                -
              </button>
            .....
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    )
  }
 }
```

**Edit**: Tried using one handler with a parameter:

App component:

```
<Table 
   data={result}
   onClick={(type) => this.changeAmount(type)}
/>
```

Table component:

```
{
   data.map(row => (
      <TableRow key={row._id} row={row} onClick={onClick}/>
   ))
}
```

TableRow component:

```
<button 
    className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm minusBtn"
    onClick={this.props.onClick('decrease')}
>
```

Comment: I would suggest to have one handler and call the same handler on both button clicks. Set the button Id and implement the logic based on button id, either decrease or increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass multiple onClick methods?

Yes, see in [**props**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) we can pass any no of data/methods to child component by any key name, it's not necessary to use name `onClick` when passing method you can use any name like `click_one`, `click_two` or `click_decrease` `click_increase`.

Like this:

```
<Table 
    data = {result}
    onClick_increase = {() => this.ABC()}
    onClick_decrease = {() => this.XYZ()}

    abc = {...}
    xyz = {...}
/>
```

Now you can access these methods from child component by `this.props.onClick_increase()` and `this.props.onClick_decrease()`.

**Another possible way:**

You can use same function with both buttons but for that pass a unique identifier from child component along with data to identified whether method is called for decrease or increase.

Like this:

```
<Table 
     data={result}
     onClick={(type, data) => this.changeAmount(type, data)}
/>

changeAmount(type, data){
    if(type == 'decrease'){
        .....
    }else{
        .....
    }
}
```

From Child:

```
this.props.onClick('decrease', data);
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working... I've updated my question to retain code formatting

Comment: can you show the updated code on pastebin both parent and child component?

Comment: Have just updated my answer to show all three components - hopefully that will give an indication of where I went wrong!

Comment: For simplicity I am only passing in one parameter and then the console.logging it

Comment: at button write it like this: `onClick={() => this.props.onClick('decrease')}` otherwise it will get called without click :)